# windows 10 - npm i @truffle/contract

Tags: smartcontracts, truffle

Can't install truffle contracts, see Error 1.

> ERROR 1:
>
> > C:\Vote>npm i @truffle/contract
> >
> > npm ERR! code ENOENT
> >
> > npm ERR! syscall spawn git
> >
> > npm ERR! path git
> >
> > npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> >
> > npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
> >
> > npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/web3 js/WebSocket-Node.git
> >
> > npm ERR! enoent
> >
> > npm ERR! enoent
> >
> > npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
> >
> > npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> >
> > npm ERR! enoent
> >
> > npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> >
> > npm ERR!     C:\Users\laure\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-11T03_41_13_180Z-debug.log

I think Error 2, happens because I haven't installed truffle contract also Error 2 happens on a local web page.

> ERROR 2:
>
> > Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: TruffleContract is not defined
> >
> > at Object.loadContract (app.js:56)
> >
> > at async Object.load (app.js:8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The give away is this line in your error log:

```
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
```

Basically, it means that the command `git` was not found and thus can not be executed.

Make sure you have installed git and added it to your environment PATH before running this install command again.